# Print out current color hex value and variable name in sass color map

Tags: sass

I am trying to create dynamic color swatches for a styleguide. I am iterating through each color in my $colors-list variable and would like to then print out the current hex value and variable names.

I would like it to look like this:

[image: I want it to look like this]

So far I can see that the hex value shows up in dev tools but is not being printed out. The variable names are also showing the hex values and it's printing out all of them. Am I missing something?

```
$colors-list: (
  $color-brand
  $color-secondary
  $color-accent
  $color-base
  $color-alert
  $color-error
  );

@each $current-color in $colors-list {
    $i: index($colors-list, $current-color);
    .color-#{$i} { 
        background-color: $current-color;
        color: white;
        float: left;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 5px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
      &:after {
          content: “hex value is #{$current-color} var name is #{$colors-list, $i}”;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 9999;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Variables don't work that way (not in Sass or any other language I am aware of).  A variable is just a reference to a value, it doesn't understand what its name is.  The only thing you can do is use a mapping (or list of lists for Sass versions older than 3.3).

```
$colors-list: (
  brand: yellow,
  secondary: blue,
  accent: green,
  base: orange,
  alert: purple,
  error: red
  );

@each $name, $color in $colors-list {
    .color-#{$name} { 
        background-color: $color;
        color: white;
        float: left;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 5px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
      &:after {
          content: "hex value is #{$color} var name is #{$name}";
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 9999;
        }
    }
}
```